# How to get the text after the last comma?

Tags: r, substring

I have a text, say:

```
s <- "Chengdu Shi, Sichuan Sheng, China"
```

I want to use a function such that I will only get the words after the last comma(i.e. China).

I have tried several methods like grep but they return all the instances instead of the last.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: take a look at `last()` from `dplyr()` or, in `base r`, access the last item of your vector with `length()`

Answer (score 2):

Using `sub`:

```
# Simply get the text after last comma ,
sub('.*\\,', '', s)
```

**OR**

Using `word` from `library(stringr)` package:

```
s <- "Chengdu Shi, Sichuan Sheng, China"
word(s,3,sep=",") # Extract word from the last column
```

OR

```
# If your data is stored in data.frame
word(s,ncol(s),sep=",") # Extract last column data using column index
```

Output:

```
[1] " China"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sapply(strsplit(s,", "),"[")[3]
[1] "China"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use stringi package

   s <- "Chengdu Shi, Sichuan Sheng, China"

    library(stringi)

    stri_extract_last_words(s)
    [1] "China"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
wordAfterLastComma <- function(x, sep = ","){
  x <- sapply(strsplit(x, sep),"[")
  trimws(x[[length(x)]])
}

s1 <- "Chengdu Shi, Sichuan Sheng, China"
s2 <- "Chengdu Shi, Sichuan Sheng, China,Chengdu Shi"

wordAfterLastComma(s1)
# [1] "China"

wordAfterLastComma(s2)
# [1] "Chengdu Shi"
```